# Video Catalog CSS and Loading (Embedded Videos)

Tags: css, wordpress, video, embed, facet

I'm looking for some help/suggestions on a project I am helping with.

The basic idea is a video catalog that host a bunch of embedded videos for people to search through (Vimeo, Youtube and Facebook for now). This is just something to test out first. I am having trouble with a few things and have been trying a lot so I wanted to get thoughts/suggestions on a direction.

The website is here currently: http://veganvideos.org/

The help that I currently am looking at is a better way to display and load the embedded videos (sometimes they are slow to load or don't) and a way to make it more responsive. Other suggestions are welcome, I very much appreciate any help.

Additional Info:

To add I am using Wordpress and FacetWP plugin currently.